# Any site to upload php code and groups of files with structure?

Tags: php, web, pastebin

For Javascript /html and css i know a few of them.

For PHP i know http://pastebin.com/ but it only allows to upload one file and not a complete application or a group of classes to show them to anyone.

Appart from GitHub, do you know any other similar site to upload code just to show it to anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many of those websites, but these come to mind:

- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)
- [Google Code](http://code.google.com/)
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)
- [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/)

Although these should be enough, what you're looking for is called "project hosting" or "code hosting".

---

EDIT:

I should note that all the websites on the list gives you access to some sort of VCS (Version Control Systems).

In a nutshell, it keeps multiple versions of your code, you could always revert back when needed.

[Read about Revision Control on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

Comment: I will try SourceForge, thanks!

Comment: @Steve I think you're supposed to "accept" the answer (if you're satisfied with it).

Comment: Sorry i forgot about it :) Done!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show a piece of code to someone, just give them the code. If you need to show a whole file, make sure everything is censored (obvious names, password etc.). Then edit the file extension to `.phps`. This means PHP Source. The source code of the file will now be shown. Then you can give people the link to the file.